# How to send and receive Data between Devices with Flutter/Dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would make an app to play with playing cards.

To make this app:

1. I must send and receive data between devices.
2. I would make it with mobile hotspot, so that all devices are in the same wireless network, also without connection to the internet.

How can I do this with Flutter/Dart? Any ideas? Or better with bluetooth? Or with internet connection?

Comment: Have you looked at any tutorials concerning your challenges? Please provide some insight or your own concerns as to why bluetooth is an option contrary to wifi, local hotspot, or other options you have spared some thought.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I didn't look at any tutorials, because I didn't find anything.... So I think mobile hotspot is the only method to send data beetween more then 2 devices.

Comment: You could also opt for Firebase Cloud Messaging. It can also be used to just send data packets.

Comment: Great question. I think if you want to do it without Internet, you can do it using Bluetooth or WiFi. It is relatively easy to get a connection, but I'm not sure how you would send/receive strings or integers using Bluetooth or WiFi. Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

I think that a way of doing this is with mobile hotspot, by using the UDP protocol of communication between devices through a local network.
There is a class in a flutter that does what you are looking for, just search for send and receive via UDP in flutter and you will find a lot of ideas, projects, classes, and packages.

Answer (score -1):

Is P2P communication between devices a hard requirement for you? Otherwise, Firebase real-time database will be an easy solution for you. This will require internet connection.